# R: How do I set two titles (main and sub-title) in each lattice xyplot?

Tags: r, lattice

I have a sample data in my R dataframe:

```
d <- read.table(text = 
"Grp     Var    Col1  Col2    Col3    Sub_grp
grp_1   8      46.8  50.0   50.6    A
grp_1   16     95.6  47.4   48.0    A
grp_1   24     45.1  45.6   46.4    A
grp_1   32     68.8  44.3   58.2    A
grp_1   40     44.6  52.2   44.3    A
grp_1   48     86.5  42.2   68.6    A
grp_2   40     63.2  95.6   63.0    B
grp_2   60     66.7  67.5   65.6    B
grp_2   80     69.6  70.7   67.9    B
grp_2   100    71.9  73.4   69.3    B
grp_2   120    73.8  75.7   48.0    B
grp_3   500    51.9  50.0   50.5    C
grp_3   1000   65.5  53.0   53.4    C
grp_3   5000   61.2  99.0   59.9    C
grp_3   10000  80.1  63.0   62.8    C
grp_3   30000  25.9  33.8   14.2    C
  ", header=T
)
```

The code below works fine and plots the data like this:

```
xyplot(
  Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | Grp,
  data=d,
  superpose=T,
  as.table=TRUE,
  col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6"),
  lwd=1.5, ylim = c(0,120),
  ylab = list(label=expression("My Values"), fontsize=15),
  xlab = list(label="Var",fontsize=15),
  key=list(
    text  = list(c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")),
    lines = list( lwd=1.5, col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6")),
    corner = c(1, 0),
    x = 0.90, 
    y = 0.17),
  par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="white")),
  scales=list(cex=1.2,x=list(relation="free")),
  type=c("l","g")
)
```

[image: plot]

Now, I would like to add column `Sub_grp` as a sub-title in each plot such that instead of one title (grp), it should have two titles (Grp and Sub_grp). I tried suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855161/how-to-set-x-labels-in-a-box-made-in-latticebwplot-that-represent-fractions-wi) at one of the relevant questions, and changed line:

```
Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | Sub_grp+Grp
```

in the above code, and my plot looks like this. Any suggestions on how this could be fixed?

[image: messy plot :(]

Answer (score 0):

Since your Grp and Sub_grp map 1:1 you can try

`Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | paste(Grp,Sub_grp,sep=" / ")`

Also consider specifying `layout=c(3,1)` to enforce the layout so your manually-placed key is where you want it.

**UPDATE to get Grp and Sub_grp on separate lines in one box.**

Use `sep="\n"` to put a line feed between the 2 parts and `par.strip.text` to control the box size to fit the 2 lines.

```
xyplot(
  Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | paste(Grp,Sub_grp,sep="\n"),
  data=d,
  superpose=T,
  as.table=TRUE,
  col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6"),
  lwd=1.5, ylim = c(0,120),
  ylab = list(label=expression("My Values"), fontsize=15),
  xlab = list(label="Var",fontsize=15),
  key=list(
    text  = list(c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")),
    lines = list( lwd=1.5, col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6")),
    corner = c(1, 0),
    x = 0.90, 
    y = 0.17),
  par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="white")),
  par.strip.text=list(lines=2),
  scales=list(cex=1.2,x=list(relation="free")),
  type=c("l","g"),layout=c(3,1)
)
```

**Update 2**

And if you are fussy and want the title and subtitles better aligned, you can pad the subtitle with spaces (assuming you know it is the shorter of the two, otherwise you need extra logic in the code).

```
d <- read.table(text = 
                  "Grp     Var    Col1  Col2    Col3    Sub_grp
grp_1   8      46.8  50.0   50.6    A
grp_1   16     95.6  47.4   48.0    A
grp_1   24     45.1  45.6   46.4    A
grp_1   32     68.8  44.3   58.2    A
grp_1   40     44.6  52.2   44.3    A
grp_1   48     86.5  42.2   68.6    A
grp_200000   40     63.2  95.6   63.0    B
grp_200000   60     66.7  67.5   65.6    B
grp_200000   80     69.6  70.7   67.9    B
grp_200000   100    71.9  73.4   69.3    B
grp_200000   120    73.8  75.7   48.0    B
grp_3   500    51.9  50.0   50.5    C
grp_3   1000   65.5  53.0   53.4    C
grp_3   5000   61.2  99.0   59.9    C
grp_3   10000  80.1  63.0   62.8    C
grp_3   30000  25.9  33.8   14.2    C
  ", header=T
)

# Set up a string of spaces corresponding to the length of Grp.
# Since the strip text is not mono-spaced, I don't use 1/2 the length
# to center the subtitle - the full length looks about right.
b <- 1
G <- as.character(d$Grp)
for(i in seq_along(G)) b[i]=paste(rep(" ",(nchar(G))[i]),collapse="")

xyplot(
  Col1 + Col2 + Col3 ~ Var | paste(Grp,paste0(b,Sub_grp),sep="\n"),
  data=d,
  superpose=T,
  as.table=TRUE,
  col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6"),
  lwd=1.5, ylim = c(0,120),
  ylab = list(label=expression("My Values"), fontsize=15),
  xlab = list(label="Var",fontsize=15),
  key=list(
    text  = list(c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")),
    lines = list( lwd=1.5, col=c("#cc0000","#008000", "#0073e6")),
    corner = c(1, 0),
    x = 0.90, 
    y = 0.17),
  par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="white")),
  par.strip.text=list(lines=2),
  scales=list(cex=1.2,x=list(relation="free")),
  type=c("l","g"),layout=c(3,1)
)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it put ´Grp_1/A´, ´Grp_2/B´, ´Grp_3/C´ in the titles of the plots. I need two title boxes like the ones shown in messy output...

Comment: If you change to `sep="\n"` it will put them on 2 lines in the same box, but the box may not be tall enough. If you condition on `|Sub_grp+Grp` I think you'll get all the combinations, including the blank ones.